# Having a dirent that is a symbolic link, how can I get the link-target's path name?

Tags: c, symlink, readdir, opendir

Having opened a directory with `opendir()` and using `readdir()` to read out it's entries, I check whether the entry is a symbolic link and if so I'd like to use the name of the target.

(Let's say we have a directory `exampledir`, in it a file that's a symbolic link called `linkfile` linking to a directory `/path/to/link/target`)

Here's a simplified snippet:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <dirent.h>
// ...
const char *path_to_dir = "./exampledir"; 
DIR *dir = opendir(path_to_dir); 
dirent *entry = readdir(dir); 
if (entry->d_type == DT_LNK) {
  // find out the link target's name and store / use it, 
  // but how...? 
}
```

Comment: Beware that the `d_type` field of `dirent` is nonstandard and is not present on all systems.

Comment: also be aware that `opendir` and `readdir` can return NULL if there was an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [readlink/readlinkat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) system call.